# Programatically creating pages in Gatsby using Json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am using gatsby to programatically create pages but I want to do so at 2 different paths covers/{json.name}.js and styles/{json.name}.js.
I have it set up currently working using the gatsby-node.js file but would prefer to have them implemented using the {} convention. Currently getting all my nodes at both paths when trying the {}.js method I am under the impression filtering is impossible using this method but is there currently a work around to get it working with the above method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly, you hit the nail. Actually, using filters/custom variables is not possible using [File System Route API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/routing/file-system-route-api/). As you can see in the [article feature announcement](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/fs-route-api/):

> **Can I use custom variables for the file name?**
>
> Defining custom variables/fields inside the file isn’t possible at the
> moment, e.g. if you want to use `{something}.js` for your file name
> and then define something as `MarkdownRemark.fields__slug`. Therefore
> you’ll have to follow the syntax of `{Model.field__nestedField}`.

There's a lack of specifications in your question so I don't know if the aliasing method will fit you (I guess it doesn't). [Aliasing](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/#aliasing) allows you to use multiple `gatsbyPath` like:

```
import React from "react"
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"

export default function HomePage(props) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.data.allProduct.map(product => (
        <li key={product.name}>
          <Link to={product.productPath}>{product.name}</Link> (
          <Link to={product.discountPath}>Discount</Link>)
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allProduct {
      name
      productPath: gatsbyPath(filePath: "/products/{Product.name}")
      discountPath: gatsbyPath(filePath: "/discounts/{Product.name}")
    }
  }
`
```

If it doesn't fit you, you won't be able to get rid of the `gatsby-node.js` so the filesystem API won't be a valid option.